# php Scandir() errors because of me or wampserver?

Tags: php, html, wamp, wampserver, scandir

When I use this code (below) it gives me 3 errors. Is it me or Wampserver? What should I do?

```
<?php
$dir = "/gallery/";
$o = scandir($dir);

print_r($o);
?>
```

Error 1:

```
Warning: scandir(/gallery/,/gallery/) [<a href='function.scandir'>function.scandir</a>]: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\wamp\www\random1\index.php on line 3
```

Error 2:

```
Warning: scandir(/gallery/) [<a href='function.scandir'>function.scandir</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\random1\index.php on line 3
```

Error 3:

```
Warning: scandir() [<a href='function.scandir'>function.scandir</a>]: (errno 2): No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\random1\index.php on line 3
```

Comment: Remove the first / in front of gallery.

Comment: You can also remove the last /

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the /gallery/ directory. The first / means it'll start searching from the root. Removing that will make it relative. So change

```
$dir = "/gallery/";
```

to

```
$dir = "gallery";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your path. Using a slash before anything in path will specify `C:\wamp` directory. Hench
`$dir = "/gallery";`, it will look into `C:\wamp`.

Suppose your directory structure is (in www\your_project directory)

```
your_file_being_executed.php
gallery
    img.jpg
```

You can use `$dir = "gallery";`
And if structure is

```
some_dir
   your_file_being_executed.php
gallery
   img.jpg
```

Then you can use `$dir = "../gallery";`

You can also `__Dir__` and `__FILE__` language constants.